# MUI tree cancel first item collapse event

Tags: material-ui, tree

i am using with v5 MUI, and How to cancel the collapse event of the first item?

[image]

Like **ALL** in the picture

and **remove** dropdown icon

like list item in the picture

Comment: Are you managing the state of the expanded items yourself or are you using the TreeView uncontrolled?

Comment: I just wish I could turn off the collapse of the first item(like ALL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no way to disable the expand/collapse functionality of an individual [`TreeItem`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tree-item/) in uncontrolled mode (if that's what you're running). Presumably, you should be able to easily change your [`TreeView`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tree-view/) to run in controlled mode, by keeping the expanded item list in state, passing that list to the `TreeView`'s [`expanded`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tree-view/#props) prop, and then force it to keep top-level items expanded by not providing a click handler for the `TreeItem`(s) that you don't want to collapse. For example:

```
...

  // Setting the top-level node's nodeId to "expanded", by default
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(["1"]);

  // Handle the expand logic however you choose (this is just an example)
  const createHandler = (id) => () => {
    if (!expanded.includes(id)) {
      setExpanded([...expanded, id]);
    } else {
      setExpanded(
        expanded.filter((i) => {
          return i !== id && !i.startsWith(`${id}.`);
        })
      );
    }
  };

...

return (
    <TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      expanded={expanded}
    >
      {/* Don't provide a click handler to this node so it won't collapse */}
{/* Note: I'm passing an empty fragment to the `collapseIcon` prop so no collapse icon is displayed */}
      <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="All Items" collapseIcon={<></>}>
        {/* Provide a click handler for all collapsible children */}
        <TreeItem
          nodeId="2"
          label="Second Level Item"
          onClick={createHandler("2")}
        />

        ...

   </TreeView>
);

...
```

The example above also includes a method for removing the collapse icon by passing an empty React Fragment to the `collapseIcon` prop -- But you could also achieve this with some clever CSS, if you prefer.

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4nmsp6?file=/demo.tsx:1514-1699